# VueI18n Translation warnings

Tags: vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

On my project we are using VueI18n package for translation purpouose.
But through application's console I am constantly getting warnings similar to this one :

```
[vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'Dashboard'. Use the value of keypath as default.
```

The line of code that is responsible for using VueI18n instance in Vue app is this one inside app.js :

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
Vue.use(VueI18n);
```

I have tried to pass object to a VueI18n constructor in order to set **silentTranslationWarn: true,**
but I am then getting the following error inside the console:

**app.js?id=cb36b063ab958b6735fd:225488 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_vm')**

How my code looks like :

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    silentFallbackWarn: true,
}));
```

VueI18n constructor from my package looks like this :
  `constructor(options?: VueI18n.I18nOptions)` and it implements I18nOptions interface :

```
  interface I18nOptions {
    locale?: Locale;
    fallbackLocale?: FallbackLocale;
    messages?: LocaleMessages;
    dateTimeFormats?: DateTimeFormats;
    numberFormats?: NumberFormats;
    formatter?: Formatter;
    modifiers?: Modifiers,
    missing?: MissingHandler;
    fallbackRoot?: boolean;
    fallbackRootWithEmptyString?: boolean,
    formatFallbackMessages?: boolean;
    sync?: boolean;
    silentTranslationWarn?: boolean | RegExp;
    silentFallbackWarn?: boolean | RegExp;
    preserveDirectiveContent?: boolean;
    pluralizationRules?: PluralizationRulesMap;
    warnHtmlInMessage?: WarnHtmlInMessageLevel;
    sharedMessages?: LocaleMessages;
    postTranslation?: PostTranslationHandler;
    componentInstanceCreatedListener?: ComponentInstanceCreatedListener;
    escapeParameterHtml?: boolean;
  }
```

All the props specified on this interface are on this list so I don't know why exactly I am getting the following error...
Anyone who can provide me with more info I would appreciate it a lot.

I have tried passing options object into VueI18n constructor like this :

```
Vue.use(VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    silentFallbackWarn: true,
}));
```

but unfortunately I am getting the described error.